# Can we Integrate Gulp or Grunt with Magento 1.13.1.0? Trying to Optimize css, js and images

Tags: magento, gruntjs, gulp, magento-1.12

Can we Integrate Gulp or Grunt with Magento 1.13.1.0? Trying to Optimize css, js and images. There is no plugin in Magento 1.13.1.0 version but could there be any other ways to integrate it.

Appreciate your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to build a theme from scratch with grunt capabilities, then you can easily build it using a yeoman through npm. Yeoman is a web scaffolding tool so you don't have to do the hard work of installing all details.

Step 1:

install node js see [link](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Step 2:

```
npm install -g yo
```

Step 3:

```
npm install -g generator-grunt-magento
```

Step 4:

```
yo grunt-magento
```

More Details from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-grunt-magento).

Another possible solution is to create the grunt structure on an existing theme. This is something that we cannot generalize so it really depends on the theme you have and how you wan't it to be implemented.